# Place point on helix

Tags: pgfplots

Pasted below is a [helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helix) created with PGFPlots package and now I need to add points to a helix. What I was able to get so far is pasted below. I also included a figure depicting desired output I created in Matlab [[code](https://gist.github.com/3763861)].

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3+[domain=0:6*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, smooth](
  {cos(deg(x))},
  {sin(deg(x))},
  {x/(3*pi)}
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

PGFPlots example:
[image]

Matlab output:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add nodes just as you put nodes on the lines in a TikZ drawing as below or you can give 3D coordinates with an additional `\addplot3` command.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot3+[domain=0:4*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, smooth](
  {cos(deg(x))},
  {sin(deg(x))},
  {x/(3*pi)}
) node[blue,circle,fill,pos=0.3]{} node[red,draw,pos=0.65,thick]{};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]