# removing the numbering of the axis pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I remove the axes numbers on this plot [Helix](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73577/place-point-on-helix) as well as the box enclosing it?

Would it be possible to now add a tikz 3d axis with pgf plots?

```
\tdplotsetmaincoords{72}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45, tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[right, scale = .75] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[above, scale = .75] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below, scale = .75] {$x$};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for `hide axis` :

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.7}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    % necessary to get a tight bounding box 
    % (\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8} also yields correct bounding box *and*
    % correct clip path)
    clip=false,
]
\addplot3+[domain=0:6*pi, samples=100, samples y=0,no marks, smooth](
  {cos(deg(x))},
  {sin(deg(x))},
  {x/(3*pi)}
);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `clip=false` key yields a tight bounding box (necessary for pgfplots up to and including version 1.7). As of pgfplots 1.8 and with `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}` or newer, the bounding box will always be tight and the clip path can be active nevertheless.

Comment: Thanks that is great.  Would it be possible to use tikz to add in a x,y,z axis with the this or can I not combine tikz into pgfplots                       \tdplotsetmaincoords{72}{120}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round, >=triangle 45, tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,5,0) node[right, scale = .75] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,5) node[above, scale = .75] {$z$};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (6,0,0) node[below, scale = .75] {$x$};

Comment: I suppose that should become a separate question. Sounds as if you want to force pgfplots to use the same default coordinate system as tikz. In the end, the answer will be: yes, with some effort. There is some section in the pgfplots manual which addresses such a use-case. And there are the `axis cs` coordinate systems. Although I admit that I am a little bit unsure of why you hide the axis just such that you can draw it on your own? Is your question actually "how can I modify the axis' appearance"?

Comment: I didn't want that boxed axis but realized I would like to add in the 3D axis from tikz that part came later.

Comment: Ok. In addition to the mentioned manual section, you might also be interested in the key `axis lines=center` or its other values - it allows non-boxed axes.