# Spiral around cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks, fancyhdr

i want to draw a spiral around cylinder. Can you help me?

something like that http://www.unitmath.com/um/p/Examples/GeometricSolids/Spiral.gif

Thank you very much.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: this is the problem. I dont know how i could start. I know the question is very rarely. Sry.

Comment: @Goldstone You could read TikZ manual, or (if you read simple French or know a neolatin language) TikZ pour l'impatient, a very well written guide.

Answer (score 10):

The spiral can be drawn by a parameterized `plot` coordinate. The example uses a 3D coordinate system, the *z* axis is tilted 30° down.

The origin is the center point of the bottom circle.

The curves are drawn via `plot` and variable `\t`, which specifies the angle. The *x* coordinate is calculated by `cos(\t)*\cylrad` with `\cylrad` as cylinder radius. The *z* coordinate is calculated by `-sin(\t)*\cylrad`.The negative sign is due to the fact that the *z* axis points in the other direction.

The height of a point at the spiral curve grows proportionally with the angle.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  x=10mm,
  y=cos(30)*10mm,
  z={(0, -sin(30)*10mm)},
]
  \def\cylrad{1}% radius
  \def\cylht{4}
  \draw
    (-\cylrad, \cylht) -- (-\cylrad, 0) --
    plot[smooth, samples=25, variable=\t, domain=180:360]
      ({cos(\t)*\cylrad}, 0, {-sin(\t)*\cylrad}) --
    (\cylrad, \cylht)
    plot[smooth cycle, samples=51, variable=\t, domain=0:360]
      ({cos(\t)*\cylrad}, \cylht, {-sin(\t)*\cylrad})
  ;
  \draw[densely dashed]
    plot[smooth, samples=9, variable=\t, domain=0:180]
      ({cos(\t)*\cylrad}, 0, {-sin(\t)*\cylrad})
  ;
  \draw[semithick]
    \foreach \y in {0, \cylht/2} {
      plot[smooth, samples=25, variable=\t, domain=180:360]
        ({cos(\t)*\cylrad}, {\y + (\t-180)*\cylht/720}, {-sin(\t)*\cylrad})
    }
  ;  
  \draw[semithick, densely dashed]
    \foreach \y in {\cylht/4, 3*\cylht/4} {
      plot[smooth, samples=25, variable=\t, domain=0:180]
        ({cos(\t)*\cylrad}, {\y + \t*\cylht/720}, {-sin(\t)*\cylrad})
    }
  ;  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: @Goldstone: I added a `pstricks` solution to the above-mentioned link, taking as  a model the image you refer to in your post.