# How to draw a truncated cone with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I should draw a picture shown below to write an article. Although I can deal with other things, but I have no idea how to draw the truncated cone, especially two rotated ellipses. Please help me draw the truncated cone.

[image: The image that I should draw.]

Comment: Some ideas: [link1](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/truncated-cone/), [link2](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264190/spiral-on-a-truncated-cone/264213), [link3](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42812/3d-bodies-in-tikz)

Comment: Post the code for the rest and somebody will probably help with the bit you're stuck on. Right now, this is just a can't-be-bothered do-it-for-me. You may get lucky. People do answer such things. In that case, though, I'd advise wanting something cuter or more colourful or, at least, more difficult. That's more likely to get people to put in the work required to set something up from scratch.