# Geodesics on a cylinder

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I want to draw the geodesics of the cylinder.
Here's my (simple) TikZ code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.8]
                \draw (0,0) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.6cm);
                \draw (0,4) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.6cm);
                \draw [dashed] (0,1.3) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.6cm);
                \draw [dashed] (0,2.7) ellipse (1.5cm and 0.6cm);
                \draw (-1.5,0) -- (-1.5,4);
                \draw (1.5,0) -- (1.5,4);
                \draw (0,-0.6) -- (0,3.4);
        \end{tikzpicture}
```

What's missing is the helix. Is there a simple way of drawing a helix my my cylinder?
Related:
[Helix on a cylinder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129860/helix-on-a-cylinder)

Comment: More simple than any of the linked solutions?

Comment: yes. plain and simple...